# How to compare DATEDIFF to a set amount of days in a case statement residing in a report viewer

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to get a specific output for a column in the report set based on weather or not the date Uf_RequestedShipDate is 60 or more overdue when the report is ran.

I have tried Cast and Convert so far, I was previously just trying to compare the DATEDIFF output to 60 before but I keep receiving the same error.

```
, CASE
    WHEN co.Uf_RequestedShipDate = NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(day, co.Uf_RequestedShipDate, GETDATE())) <= CAST(60 AS INT) /*DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Today)*/ THEN co.Uf_RequestedShipDate + '****'
    WHEN CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(day, co.Uf_RequestedShipDate, GETDATE())) > CAST(60 AS INT) /*DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Today)*/ THEN 'Pending ****'
    END AS 'RequestedShipDate'
```

I just need it to output the date with **** or pending with **** if there is a value in the db, if it is over 60 days past that date it would be pending and if not then it should still show the date.

Examples:
I have one entry that has the date 2019-03-30 in that column, it would send 2019-03-30 **** to the report.

If there was one that had 2018-10-31 then it would just say Pending **** on the report.

If it was null for a row than it would still just be Null and no **** for the report.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I put an example in the summary to better explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: what error do you get? What datatype is Uf_RequestedShipDate ?

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EPS_Rpt_DealerSalesBacklogSp, Line 44
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare `NULL` with `=`, you must use `IS NULL`.
You don't need to convert the result of `DATEDIFF()` to integer because it is integer, so is `60`. 
The last condition: `> 60` van be just checked with an `ELSE` part in the `CASE` statement.
Try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN co.Uf_RequestedShipDate IS NULL THEN NULL
  WHEN DATEDIFF(day, co.Uf_RequestedShipDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 
    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, co.Uf_RequestedShipDate, 120) + '****'
  ELSE 'Pending ****'
END AS RequestedShipDate
```

Comment: That did it, I appreciate the help.